# Can someone give me practical benefits of using React hooks vs legacy component lifecycle with classes?

Tags: reactjs

In React docs they say that its easy to unsubscribe for listeners functions and that it shouldn't be handled in multiple places in the code.
However, easily we can achieve the same behaviour with a parent class that handles it, like this:

```
// parent class called, Base for example
subscribe(eventName, cb) { 
  sub(eventName, cb)
  eventsTrack.push({eventName, cb})
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  eventsTrack.map(({eventName, cb}) => unsub(eventName, cb))
}

// child class
class SomeClass extends Base {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.subscribe("someEvent",() => console.log("Hello World"))
  }
}
```

The second approach is even better - you don't have to remember to unsubscribe because its automatically unsubscribe when component goes off.

Maybe you guys can list some practical benefits to use the new React's functional components instead of class.

Answer (score 0):

Its shorter, all condensed into one spot and shareable by writing a custom hook to handle that for all connected components.

I do not know what `sub` does, but could also be moved into the hook.

So you could write a hook:

```
function useSubscribeHook(event, callback) {
   React.useEffect(() => {
       addEventListener(event', listener);
       return () => removeEventListener(event, listener);
   }, [event, callBack])
}
```

and just call it like this:

```
const callback = React.useCallback(() => console.log("Hello World"), []);
useSubscribeHook('someEvent', callback);
```